# Can I replace 均 with 都 here?

Tags: meaning

Is this sentence still acceptable if I replace 均 with 都？ Or to put that another way, have I got the meaning of 均 here correct?

发达国家对产品生产等整个过程**均**需符合环保要求。

发达国家对产品生产等整个过程**都**需符合环保要求。

Comment: Reechen, Chinese is very tricky, how am I supposed to know all the intricacies of this ancient language? 我是老外！Use a different word, and the meaning can shift, but I would not know.

Comment: You mean comments like 'look it up in a dictionary'? I entirely agree!

Comment: o d provide a large number of sample sentences intended to show the range of applicability of each word，this is particularly true of the adverbs都 and 均，e。g。iciba has more than １００ for 均（after reaching １００ gave up counting） and can there be any doubt that for 都 the number is even greater？In particular iciba has ５３。 准备出国者均需注射伤寒预防针 containing 均需。Also iciba 句库 has many sample sentences for 都需 （when reaching ３０ gave up counting）。P。S。iciba 句库 also has more than ４０sample sentences for 均需。 线上词典提供大量例句旨在显示大多数词语的可用范围，至于＂均＂来说，有超过100个例子（达到100后，笔者放弃了计数），并毫无疑问关于＂都＂的数字甚至更大。情况甚‌​至比这更好些，其实爱词霸有大量包含＂均需＂与＂都需＂的例句。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. In this context, both `均` and `都` mean `all`. `均` slightly indicates the variety of the processes.

`均需` is formal and usually used in writing or lectures. `都要` would be one of the informal equivalents.